# Spring Batch : How to instantiate "Step" scope bean in Cucumber Testing?

Tags: spring, cucumber, spring-batch, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

How to instantiate "Step" scope bean of spring in Cucumber Testing?

SpringJUnit4ClassRunner uses @TestExecutionListeners to instantiate the step scoped beans for testing purpose.

I am trying get this behavior in Cucumber. Cucumber uses a @RunWith(Cucumber.class)

Is there anyway we can instantiate step scope bean?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Cucumber, but I have instantiated/tested step scope items using `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`

I would recommend including the `StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class` as well as the `DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener` (if you're injecting any dependencies) in your `@TestExecutionListeners` annotation, e.g. `@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class })`

In order to instantiate a step scope bean in the test class, first get an instance of the `ExecutionContext` by utilizing the `MetaDataInstanceFactory`.

For example:

```
ExecutionContext executionContext = MetaDataInstanceFactory.createJobExecution().getExecutionContext();
```

Once you can have an instance of the `ExecutionContext`, you'll need to make use of the `JobLauncherTestUtils` class (documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/test/JobLauncherTestUtils.html). You can launch a step by calling `launchStep()`, for example:

```
jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep(<step_name>, <job_parameters>, <execution_context>);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the details. I do have same implementation. I am want to try using CUCUMBER only. I may be too early on this open source product.

Listeners functionality is provided by Spring runner and same thing should be provided in CUCUMBER.

Answer (score 0):

By exploring some options i have made it workable for now.

Below is my workaround

Bean Configuration

```
@Bean(name = "abc")
@StepScope
public ABC getABC(){
return new ABC();
}

@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfiguration.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class StepDef {

@Autowire
ABC abc;

public StepDef{

         StepExecution stepExecution = getStepExecution();
         StepSynchronizationManager.register(stepExecution);

}

}
```

I am not sure how correct is this implementation. I have initialize the StepExecution to load my configuration in stepDef Constructor so my AutoWiring can work properly and i can run my test against it.

I need to follow same approach for all stepDef , may be i will write a super class and implement that in super constructor.

Do let me know if you see any concerns.

Thanks again